# JavaScript form validation. Forms sent event if fields are required

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I got this form somebody else made. It's a really simple form. Problem is, the client is receiving empty submits. The form already has some validation on it so I'm wondering how can it be submitted.

```js
function check_message() {
  var check = true;
  if (document.getElementById('email').value == '') {
    check = false;
    document.getElementById('email').style.border = '3px solid red';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('email').style.border = '1px solid #cccccc';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('telephone').value == '') {
    check = false;
    document.getElementById('telephone').style.border = '3px solid red';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('telephone').style.border = '1px solid #cccccc';
  }
  if (check) {
    document.getElementById('thaForm').submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="thatForm" name="" action="soumission_process.php" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" size="40" value="">
  <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="" size="40" value="">
  <input type="button" value="send" onClick="check_message();">
</form>
```

In the soumission_process.php, it's just :

```
$email= $_POST['email'];
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
```

Then mail the stuff...

How could somebody submit the form skipping the validation ? I though maybe the form is just filled with blank space than submitted but there's a required SELECT and it's empty too. If I try myself, I can't submit without filling all the fields and selecting an option in that select.

Help me with that weird Wordpress saved as html site :D

Comment: I made you a snippet but had to add a `}` to the script. You are likely getting empty or hacked form entries because the bots do not care about the javascript, they just take the action

Comment: So a bot could just ignore the js and do the form submit by it's own ? Would adding the html "required" to the fields fix that ? <input type="text" required>

Comment: Or would it best to check on the php side too before sending mails ?

Comment: Best check on the server since the bot ignores anything

Comment: trim whitespace before validating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check form datas in the php script, ex :

```
if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && (isset($_POST['telephone']) && $_POST['telephone'] != '')){
  $email= $_POST['email'];
  $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
  // mail datas
}else{
  // do nothing or display error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1
Add required to each field - this will not stop bots from harvesting and submitting post requests to the action

Solution 2

Remove the action and add it if all is ok

In BOTH cases check on the server

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("thatForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    var allOk = 0;
    var emailField = document.getElementById('email');
    var ok = emailField.value.trim() !== '' ? 1 : 0; allOk += ok;
    emailField.classList.toggle("error", !ok)
    var telephoneField = document.getElementById('telephone')
    ok = telephoneField.value.trim() !== '' ? 1 : 0; allOk += ok;
    telephoneField.classList.toggle("error", !ok)
    if (allOk !== 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    this.action = "soumission_process.php"
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: 3px solid red
}
```

```html
<form id="thatForm" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" size="40" value="">
  <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="" size="40" value="">
  <input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```